# Edit observable on method called

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an observable coming from the store service NgRx with an array of Replies

```
public replies$: Observable<Reply[]> = this.storeService.getMessageReplies();
```

I have a method that should mark as read a reply if clicked

```
  public markReplyAsRead(reply: Reply): void {
    console.log('id: ', reply.id, reply.replyStatus);
    if (reply.replyStatus === this.replyStatuses.READ) return;

    this.storeService.markReplyAsRead(reply.id, this.data);
    this.replies$.pipe(map(replies => {
      replies.filter(reply => reply.id
    }))
  }
```

I am new to RxJs so I don't know how to put this
I tried to apply map and filter the array but it's not working

How can I update the observable? I don't want to refetch again the data after click

Comment: You probably need to subscribe to `storeService.markReplyAsRead()`, ideally, that would cause your observable to emit the updated state. `this.replies$.pipe(…)` doesnt do anything unless you subscribe, but it can be removed if the method causes the `getMessageReplies()` observable to emit the updated state.

Comment: You should probably also include the code of the reducer if your code does not show the correct behavior. Nevertheless you can remove the `pipe` call since it does not have any effect (the returned observable is not stored anywhere). Additional note: you are returning undefined from your map function, since you are not returning the filtered array. In order to return it, you should remove the curly brackets or explicitly include `return …`.